# GetGeopoint from a some Address

Tags: c#, openstreetmap

I use OpenStreetMap and need to optain a geopoint for a needed address. I can optain this one using Geocoding so:

```
Geocoding.IGeocoder geocoder = new Geocoding.Google.GoogleGeocoder();
var addresses = geocoder.Geocode("my address");
lat = addresses.First().Coordinates.Latitude;
lng = addresses.First().Coordinates.Longitude;
```

there are a similary solution for OsmSharp ???
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no official geocoding module for OsmSharp, see [issue 16](https://github.com/OsmSharp/core/issues/16). However I found an inofficial [Nominatim module for OsmSharp](https://github.com/pauldendulk/OsmSharp/tree/master/OsmSharp/GeoCoding/Nominatim). Nominatim is an OSM-based geocoder.

Of course you could also query it yourself by sending corresponding HTTP requests. See the [Nominatim documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) for details.